# express-openapi-validator/dist/resolvers.js: require() of ES Module not supported

Tags: javascript, node.js, openapi, es6-modules

I have generated a server with `openapi-express-server` but I need to convert it to ES6 as I will be using some libraries that do not support CommonJS anymore so I cannot use require for them.
I generated a basic server to test the refactor but I keep getting an error from resolver.js. I have tried with express-openapi-validator v3, v4 and v5.

Server loads up correctly, but when an API is called I get the error:

```bash
require() of ES Module /controllers/InfoController.js from /node_modules/express-openapi-validator/dist/resolvers.js not supported.\nInstead change the require of InfoController.js in /node_modules/express-openapi-validator/dist/resolvers.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules."
```

This is the Controller that is giving the error, but also all the others controllers will throw an error if used. The error appears not on the server startup but on the first API call to the REST endpoint (in this case `info/version`)

```js
// InfoController.js
import Controller from './Controller.js';
import service from '../services/InfoService.js';

const version = async (request, response) => {
  await Controller.handleRequest(request, response, service.version);
};

export default {
  version,
};
```

Seems like resolver.js inside the openapi-validator library does not like es6 modules. What can I do to solve this?

Generate a server with openapi-express-server Generator and convert the files to ES6 standard. I expected the APIs to work normally.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. You can fix this by [defining your own resolver](https://github.com/cdimascio/express-openapi-validator/wiki/Documentation#%EF%B8%8F-operationhandlers-optional). You can find the [example here](https://github.com/cdimascio/express-openapi-validator/tree/master/examples/5-custom-operation-resolver).

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/997587